# ATmega328 - two clock outputs

Tags: clock

I'm using an ATmega328P to provide a software-selectable 2, 4 or 8 MHz clock to my home made SBC.  This works just fine.  However, I am adding a programmable sound generator (PSG) to the board and it requires a 1-2MHz clock.

I want to keep the board simple and avoid flip-flop clock dividers and output selects due to the variable system clock speed, so I was hoping I could configure the ATmega328P to provide a second (non-variable) 2 MHz clock for the PSG.

Problem is, I'm not experienced with AVRs and their timer fuses and don't even know if this is possible with the ATmega328P?  If it is, how can I set up another pin to and its timer to provide the 2 MHz clock signal?

Bonus (almost unrelated) question: Can a 20 MHz AVR provide an 8 MHz clock pulse, as it's not a factor of 20?

EDIT:  Just to clarify a couple of points:

1) The ATmega328 is running at 16 MHz.  I'm using one clock/timer output to produce the required 8 MHz clock I need for the main board.

2) I need a separate (but ideally in-step with the 8 MHz clock) 2 MHz clock for the PSG.  I was hoping to be able to set up another clock output from the ATmega328?

Comment: In what shape exactly do you need your 1 MHz clock, and your 8MHz clock? I'm not deep enough into the atmega family, but you can probably do the 1MHz with a PWM unit.

Comment: Completely a non-answer, but you might want to consider a clock generator chip with I2C interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not deep enough into the atmega family, but you can probably do the 1MHz with a PWM unit. These are programmable, so you can adjust them to varying system clocks if necessary.

The 8 MHz will be harder, but if you can generate integer factors of 20 MHz:

- generate 4 MHz square wave
- convert square wave (which has a lot of odd order harmonics) to sine wave with very simple RC or LC low pass filter
- rectify sine wave » signal with frequency content at twice the sine's frequency (amongst others)
- filter rectified sine wave to *only* contain the desired 8MHz sine wave
- use comparator or Schmitt trigger to convert sine wave to square wave, if latter is desired

Comment: PWM? I think you mean PLL.

Comment: no, actually not, @Curd. OP's (as far as I can tell) running with a system clock of 20 MHz, so 1MHz would simply be a PWM unit that counts from 20 down to 0 and inverts an output halfway through that.

Comment: Why not just use then counter/timer to generate a clock divided by 2?

Comment: a counter / timer module == PWM unit, usually.

Comment: I wouldn't call it PWM module when there is not nothing to pulse width modulate.

Comment: call it what you will – the datasheet calls it "8-bit Timer/Counter with PWM", so I think none of us is especially right or wrong - I'd call any timer with a counter and a compare unit a PWM unit anytime, because it has all the features of a PWM unit.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've edited the question for more clarity, but I'm already producing an 8 MHz clock signal from the ATmega.  I want to know if (and maybe how) I could produce ANOTHER clock signal, at 2 MHz, from the same device?

Comment: The atmega328 has multiple timer units. So, yeah, same way as you produce the 8 MHz.

Comment: The 8 MHz could be coming from the System Clock output pin,  by programming bit 6 of the Low Fuse byte to 0.  "The CKOUT Fuse allows the system clock to be output on PORTB0. Refer to Clock Output Buffer section in the System Clock and Clock Options chapter for details."  If the system clock is 20 MHz, 20 MHz should be coming out on this pin also if the bit is programmed.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider this chip

https://www.renesas.com/us/en/www/doc/datasheet/82c54.pdf
https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=CP82C54

Feed it with 8, 10, 12 MHZ clock, program it to output desired frequency.

Comment: Now that's a blast from the past.

Comment: Still available - I just designed a board with 16 of them for 48 clock outputs.

Comment: Okay, interesting chip - thanks for the suggestion (shame it's so expensive!)  I sorted this issue well over a year ago, btw, as I got to grips with the ATmega and used two PWM outputs with 50% duty cycle in the end.